# Why is this first-order ODE amenable to the method of integrating factor/separable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

**Background**

We know that the first order differential equation in the form 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x)$$
is amenable to the method of integrating factor

**Question**

How is this first order equation amenable to the method of integrating factor? The equation seems not to be in the desired form.

$$y^{\prime}+y=\frac{2 x e^{-x}}{1+y e^{x}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^{\prime}+y=\frac{2 x e^{-x}}{1+y e^{x}}$$
This ODE is not on the form 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x)$$
because  $q(x)\neq q(x,y)=\frac{2 x e^{-x}}{1+y e^{x}}$ .
$$y^{\prime}+y=\frac{2 x e^{-2x}}{e^{-x}+y}$$
Change of function :
$$u(x)=e^{-x}+y(x)\quad\implies\quad y=u-e^{-x}$$
$$y'=u'+e^{-x}$$
$$y^{\prime}+y=(u'+e^{-x})+(u-e^{-x})=\frac{2 x e^{-2x}}{u}$$
Now the equation is a separable.
$$(u'+u)u=2 x e^{-2x}$$
Let $\quad u^2=v(x)$
$$\frac12\: \frac{dv}{dx}+v(x)=2 x e^{-2x}$$
This is a first order linear ODE.

Answer (score 1):

The left side is related to the derivative of $u(x)=e^xy(x)$. More specifically,
$$
u'(x)=e^x(y'+y)=\frac{2x}{1+u(x)}
$$
which is separable,
$$
(1+u(x))^2=2x^2+C
$$